# Hierarchy of facet fields (not hierarchical facets) in Apache Solr?

Tags: solr, lucene, faceted-search, facet

I´m trying to setup a search across multiple document types, each with different sets of fields. So the search should always start with only the most general facet field (eg Product category), common to all document types.

```
PRODUCT CATEGORY  
- Camera (42)  
- TV & Video (96)  
- MP3 Player (11)  
- Video Game (63)
```

After selecting "Camera", I need to enable a whole set of new facet fields, exclusive to that document type (eg Brand, Capacity), like the following:

```
PRODUCT CATEGORY  
> Camera

BRAND  
- Canon (42)  
- Nikon (96)  
- Sony (11)  
- Samsung (63)

CAPACITY  
- 1Gb (42)  
- 2Gb (96)  
- 3Gb (11)  
- 4Gb (63)
```

I know this can be done by managing `facet.field` query parameters programmatically, but is there any better way to build this systematically? Is there any feature or tip to allow this facet fields dependency inside Solr and its field structures?

Thanks a lot!

**Edit:** I changed the title from "dependency of facet fields".

Answer (score 2):

IMO you do not need to create any dependency.
You can create individual fields for this entries.

When you do an Initial Query you would facet on Product Type.
Then when you filter on a specific product type, you are only going to get facets from the results as per the filter.

For e.g. 
Product Type Camera would have Brands Canon, Nikon as so on ... with some capacity options
Product Type TV & Video would have Brands Song, Samsung as so on ... with some other attributes

So when you would Filter on Camera (`fq=product_type:Camera`) you would limit the results only for Product Type Camera and Brands within this filter with capacity options.
The filtering should take care of the dependency.

Comment: Yes, `field.facet` on the inicial query, and `fq` on its facet links? This seems a great idea only for 2 levels of this "field hierarchy" (1-Product category / 2-Brand, Capacity). But there´s no real field dependency that would alow more levels, isn´t it?

Comment: I think if he wants to enforce the order in which facets are chosen, he must use some hierarchy, as the user would be able to filter on lets say price after (fq=product_type:Camera) even if he wants only Brand and Capacity to be available

Comment: You are right, and that "some hierarchy" is what I am looking for: a field hierarchy for faceting (I am even going to rewrite the title). As there seems to be no such functionality, is it custom code the only way out?

Comment: Thanks Jayendra, yes I did. I am now reviewing it as you suggested, will comment back soon.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by ensuring you index the appropiate info in each document, look at [this wiki page on hierarchical facetting](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HierarchicalFaceting)

Comment: Yes I did read it, and indeed there is a hierarchy, but not of facets. This is about hierarchy between fields. In my example, it´s kinda like **Brand** and **Capacity** were "child" fields of **Product category**, in such way that filtering on a parent field would automatically anable faceting on child fields.

Comment: what about adding such a field with values like 0/Canon, 1/Canon/4Gb, etc?

Comment: Interesting, you mean bringing the 3 fields together, as levels os a single hierarchical field? Wouldn´t it be too restrictive? In my case 1 field enables 2 others (or more), but wouldn´t your suggestion lead to strictly single childs? And how would I keep the separate display of fields, like I illustrated on the gray box?

Comment: single child: no, look at the wiki page, not sure if you understood the mechanism. You can add several values at any level: 0/Canon, 1/Canon/4G, 1/Canon/150$

Comment: Sorry, I said "single child" about the hierarchy of fields, not their values. Like `Category` leads only to `Brand` thand only to `Capacity`. Anyway, in this last example of yours, how would you separate the values of brand, capacity and price (is "150$" price?) ?

Comment: (btw thanks for your answers, I just don´t have reputation enough to vote it up)